# Scrapy. How to yield item after spider_close call?

Tags: scrapy

I want to yield an item only when the crawling is finished.
I am trying to do it via

```
def spider_closed(self, spider):
    item =  EtsyItem()
    item['total_sales'] = 1111111
    yield item
```

But it does not yield anything, though the function is called.
How do I yield an item after the scraping is over?

Comment: spider_closed is used when you have finished scraping (item yielding), in case you want to add a value depending on the yielded items you can open the written file and read it from there. I see no other reason you want to yield in spider_closed

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you want to do, there might be a veeeery hacky solution for this.

Instead of `spider_closed` you may want to consider using `spider_idle` signal which is fired before `spider_closed`. One difference between idle and close is that `spider_idle` **allows execution of requests** which then may contain a callback or errback to yield the desired item.

Inside spider class:

```py
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
    # ...
    crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_idle, signal=signals.spider_idle)
    return spider

# ...

def yield_item(self, response):
    yield MyItem(name='myname')


def spider_idle(self, spider):
    req = Request('https://fakewebsite123.xyz',
        callback=lambda:None, errback=self.yield_item)
    self.crawler.engine.crawl(req, spider)
```

However this comes with several side effects so i discourage anyone from using this in production, for example the final request which will raise a `DNSLookupError`. I just want to show what is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Oof, I'm afraid `spider_closed` is used for tearing down. I suppose you can do it by attaching some custom stuff to `Pipeline` to post-process your items.